# I need to perform a SUM operation in SQL

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sum

Okay, these are my tables:

```
  EMPLOYEE         STORE          BORROW                 UNIFORM
- EMP_ID         - STORE_ID     - UNIFORM_ID           - UNIFORM_ID
- EMP_NAME       - STORE_NAME   - BORROW_START_DATE    - UNIFORM_COST
- STORE_ID                      - BORROW_END_DATE
                                - EMP_ID
```

I need to have a function that returns the total cost of uniforms that are currently being borrowed by each employee from each store.
I need it to look something like this

```
Store Name      Total Uniform Costs
North Store     $4,250
East Store      $2,500
South Store     $2,750
West Store      $3,000
```

I have no idea where to start, I know I need to use a GROUP BY clause, but I'm not sure how to use it. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

This simple query should get you the results you want:

```
select s.STORE_NAME, sum(u.UNIFORM_COST) as TotalCost
from STORE s
inner join EMPLOYEE e on e.STORE_ID = s.STORE_ID
inner join BORROW b on b.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID
inner join UNIFORM u on u.UNIFORM_ID = b.UNIFORM_ID
group by s.STORE_NAME
```

First step is to join all tables required to get us some connection between store and uniform cost, so to connect both tables we have to get all employees in store and their borrowings. After that we are summing uniform costs to get total value and last we have to group our results by store name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect Store table with Uniform table using joins

```
select STORE_NAME, sum ( UNIFORM_COST) as TotalUniformCosts
from STORE s
inner join EMPLOYEE e
   on s.STORE_ID=e.STORE_ID
inner join BORROW b
   on e.EMP_ID=b.EMP_ID
inner join UNIFORM u
   on b.UNIFORM_ID=u.UNIFORM_ID
group by STORE_NAME
```